# Give Server internet access over a P2P network using Debian 7

Tags: networking, debian, centos

I have set up a simple P2P network between my desktop PC (running Debian 7) and my home server (running CentOS 6.5). I am able to ping between the two systems, and they connected via a wired Ethernet cable. The desktop PC connects to a normal LAN via a wireless NIC to a wireless router (which in turn is connected to the Internet).

My problem is that I want the server to be able to access the Internet for upgrades etc. However, when I try to go on the Internet using a browser the domain name can't be found, and pinging www.google.com gives the error `Destination host unreachable`.

What can I configure on the Debian machine to allow the server to access the internet?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable ipv4 traffic forwarding on the debian machine as root :

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward  (note this does not survive reboots)

Then you need a route on your internet router for the subnet between debian and centos. This route should point to the ip address of the wifi interface of the debian.